# Brighness controls on Toshiba Tecra

Tags: brightness, acpi, toshiba

The brightness controls do not have any visible effect on my Toshiba Tecra W50. I tried every combination of `acpi_brightness=vendor` and `acpi_osi=Linux` to no avail.

How can I change my screen's brightness?

Notes:

- I've installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers for my graphics card.
- The only entry in `sys/class/backlight` is `video0`
- For `video0`, `max_brightness`, `brightness`, and `actual_brightness` are all 100.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons set the value in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`, which has no effect. Using `xbacklight`, however, works well:

```
xbacklight -set 50
```

Another way to achieve the same result is to use `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --set Backlight 50
```

You can then remap the function keys to two scripts containing `xbacklight -inc 10` and `xbacklight -dec 10`. On Mint, you do this by creating a custom keyboard shortcut.